# Opennebula 3.2.1 noVNC on sunstone missing plain.css and vnc.js

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I was just finished install opennebula and sunstone on ubuntu server 12.04. and i deployed an vm but i can't open the vnc from sunstone.

i have fixed the noVNC installation on sunstone using step from http://lists.opennebula.org/pipermail/users-opennebula.org/2012-May/018989.html.

below is the error from sunstone log.

```
...
/var/log/one/sunstone.log:x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2013 21:54:37] "GET /vendor/noVNC/include/plain.css HTTP/1.1" 404 471 0.0007
/var/log/one/sunstone.log:x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2013 21:54:53] "GET /vendor/noVNC/include/vnc.js HTTP/1.1" 404 468 0.0009
...
```

plain.css and vnc.js is missing from novnc installation. i've tried to search the missing files on the system and also checked novnc github with no avail.

is the missing files is the problem that i can't open vnc from sunstone? i can access vnc using vncviewer directly to vm vnc port.
is there anyone have information where to find that missing files?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I can't find solution for novnc problem on opennebula package for ubuntu 12.04 (opennebula 3.2.1).

The workaround is to install opennebula 3.8.3 from opennebula.org (they provide deb package for ubuntu, debian and others distribution also). and I haven't found any problem so far using this version of opennebula, all functions seem run perfectly including novnc.